# How to center a UIButton after device is rotated in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, centering

I have created a UIButton programmatically and horizontally centered it using the following code

```
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 50);
```

When device is rotated, it's no longer in the center. How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin is correct, but a better solution would be to set the button's center in your view controller's `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 50);
}
```

He uses the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation`  method, which, as the Apple documentation states "*this method might be used to reenable view interactions, start media playback again, or turn on expensive drawing or live updates.*"

In the case of laying out subviews, the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` will provide a smoother transition, as it is called from within the rotation's animation block.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 50);
}
```